# Inno Setup - Setup.exe works locally, but not as a download

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, github, inno-setup

I compiled my first program this with Inno setup for a python 2.7 script with connections to opencv and numpy. The setup.exe works perfectly on my computer locally. It installs, it runs, there are no detectable errors.

When i go to make the setup.exe available through github:
https://github.com/bw4sz/OpenCV_HummingbirdsMotion/tree/master/Installer/Output

I can download the setup.exe, but on the SAME computer, it won't install: Error reads, the Windows version of the software is not compatible with the version you are running, check with the system if you need a x86 (64) or 32 bit version.

This is confusing to me, since the program was designed on this machine, and i just need to distribute it. Do i fundamentally not understand what Inno Setup does, i.e that a user needs to do more than download the setup.exe. I can provide scripts if needed.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

It depends on github. In a quick way I found [this link](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software), hope it help.